# re-create an Object to be 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this

```
{ '2020-08': {Invoice: 21400, Receipt: 20800, ...},
  '2020-09': {Invoice: 8003.6, ...},
  '2020-10': {Receipt: 7779.2, ...},
  '2020-11': {Invoice: 32970, ...}
}
```

Wanna make it to be 2d array like this

```
[ ['2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11'],
  [   21400 ,   8003.6 ,        0 ,    32970 ], //Invoice
  [   20800 ,        0 ,   7779.2 ,        0 ], //Receipt
  ...
]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to achieve using Object.keys.

```js
const data = {
  '2020-08': {
    Invoice: 21400,
    Receipt: 20800
  },
  '2020-09': {
    Invoice: 8003.6,
    Receipt: 7779
  },
  '2020-10': {
    Receipt: 7779.2,
    Invoice: 32970
  },
  '2020-11': {
    Invoice: 32970,
  }
}

const res = []
const keys = [...Object.keys(data)]
const d = Object.keys(data).map(item => {
  return data[item]["Invoice"] || 0
})
const d1 = Object.keys(data).map(item => {
  return data[item]["Receipt"] || 0
})
console.log([keys, d, d1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
let result = [], key= [], invoice= [], receipt = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((x) => {
    key.push(x);
    invoice.push(obj[x].Invoice || 0);
    receipt.push(obj[x].Receipt || 0);
});
result = [key,invoice,receipt];
```